# Constructing a Differential Structure

Tags: smooth-manifolds

I am currently undergoing a first course on Differentiable Manifolds. An an example I was trying to construct a differential structure for a 2D unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$. By definition, the coordinate charts are as follows:
\begin{array}{ c c}
 U_1=\{(x,y,z):z>0\} & \phi_1(x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})=(x,y) \\ 
 U_2=\{(x,y,z):z<0\} & \phi_2(x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})=(x,y) \\  
 U_3=\{(x,y,z):x>0\} & \phi_3(x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})=(y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}) \\
  U_4=\{(x,y,z):x<0\} & \phi_4(x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})=(y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}) \\
U_5=\{(0,1,0)\} & \phi_5(0,1,0)=(0,1) \\
U_6=\{(0,-1,0)\} & \phi_6(0,-1,0)=(0,-1) 
\end{array}
Have I done this correctly ? Now I want to find a differential structure $\mathscr{F}$ on $\mathbb{S}^2$. For this I need to show that each composition map $\phi_j\circ\phi_i^{-1},\: i\neq j \in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is $C^\infty$, $X=\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$ and $\mathscr{F}$ is maximal. I am very confused about how to proceed ? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.